# Footer not keeping the bottom position

Tags: html, css, footer

i've a problem with the css of a page. The template has been renewed from an old one so i had to write from scratch some parts, but it's ok, except from the footer. It "seems" ok, but when you click crtl - many times you'll see that the footer doesn't stick at the bottom of the page, it goes up with the rest of the conent. I'm not very found of this. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekq3S/). I guess the mistake is something trivial but i still have to find it.
The code is the following:

```
 <body>
 <div id="sito">
 <div class="header">
      <div class="content">
         <div class="boxgrigio">
             <div class="content">
                 <div class="email"></div></div></div>
         <div class="contatti_elenco">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
                <div id="slideshow">
                    <div id="featured">
                    <div class="ui-tabs-panel"></div>
    </div></div></div></div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The CSS is very easy and is in the fiddle provided.
Please help!

Comment: Do you want the footer to be permanently visible ? like it's stuck to the bottom of the browser window ?

Comment: change to `position: fixed;` in `.footer` class [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekq3S/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix footer like this:

```
   .footer {
       position:fixed;/* change to this */
       left:0px;
       bottom:0px;
       height:--px;
       width:100%;
       background:#color;
    }

    /* IE 6 */
    * html .footer {
       position:absolute;
       top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
    }
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekq3S/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In footer class change `position` value `position: fixed;`

```
.footer{
    width:100%;
    font-size: 13px;    
    background-color: #404040;
    position: fixed;
    height:120px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekq3S/1/show/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set images like a background for example to scale properly
[Scalable background](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)
...but as far as all your html content its rather tricky.. There is some javascript options for this though. 
Such as [Detect zoom and scale](https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom)

This is assuming you want your page to actually be 100% of viewport... Not just your footer sticking to bottom...